# I need to change the time format in my DataFrame

Tags: r

- 

Hello people,

I have a Column of a dataframe that shows the time of a departure. The problem i have is that 6 am shows like 6:00 and I need it to be 06:00.

My dataframe looks like this:

| Van ID | Departure |
| --- | --- |
| 0034 | 6:00 |
| 1973 | 12:00 |
| 7679 | 21:00 |
| 2532 | 9:00 |

And I need it to be like this:

| Van ID | Departure |
| --- | --- |
| 0034 | 06:00 |
| 1973 | 12:00 |
| 7679 | 21:00 |
| 2532 | 09:00 |

Is there a function that helps me do this fast? I have like 2000 observations and I cant go one by one changing them.

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `base R`, can convert to Datetime object and then use `format`

```
df1$Departure <- format(as.POSIXct(df1$Departure, format = "%H:%M"), "%H:%M")
```

-output

```
> df1
  VanID Departure
1  0034     06:00
2  1973     12:00
3  7679     21:00
4  2532     09:00
```

---

Or may use regex replacement

```
df1$Departure <- sub("^(\\d):", "0\\1:", df1$Departure)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(VanID = c("0034", "1973", "7679", "2532"), 
Departure = c("6:00", 
"12:00", "21:00", "9:00")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```